# TclOO : Get the name of class where the object was created

Tags: tcl

I have two classes  :

```
oo::class create p1 {
    constructor {} {
        # Here I would like to know where the object was created.
        # Inside second class or other
    }
}

oo::class create p2 {
    constructor {} {

    }
}

oo::define p2 {
    method testSecond {} {
        set obj [p1 new]
    }
}
set obj1 [p1 new]
set obj2 [p2 new]

$obj2 testSecond
```

I have try :
`puts "Infoname Class= [info object class [self]]"` inside `p1` class constructor. But each time I have `Infoname Class= ::p1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are created globally, so they store no information about who created them.

If you insist, you can check via `uplevel` in the constructor:

```
oo::class create p1 {
    constructor {} {
        set ns [uplevel 1 [list namespace current]]
        if {[info object isa object $ns]} {
            puts "Infoname Class= [info object class $ns]"
        } else {
            puts Other
        }
    }
}
```

But that is very fragile. I would not recommend it.

Comment: It's fine for logging and other immediate purposes, but not a very good plan to retain as the object that asked for the creation might itself go away. It would be different if you were explicitly passing it in; there you'd have the *expectation* of collaboration.

Comment: You might also get the check working using `info stack`, but that's quite a bit trickier to use.